# .htaccess friendly url. What am i doing wrong

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have the following link which is working:

```
jobdetails.php?url=Human-Resoure-Manager-3-5
```

I want to convert it to a friend link below but i don't know what wrong with my htaccess:

```
/jobdetails/Human-Resoure-Manager-3-5
```

---

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^jobdetails/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ jobdetails.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1):

You're not matching the dashes "-", try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^jobdetails\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/$ jobdetails.php?url=$1
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am still getting the same "/jobdetails/Human-Resoure-Manager-3-5 was not found on this server.'

Comment: try escaping the slashes? I edited my example to reflect.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I have just given up

Comment: regerx.com might help

Answer (score 0):

After extensive searching in discovered that i was leaving out ?  before $ jobdetails/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ **was forgeting to put ? here** $